# how to use where in firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, where-clause

I've built an app using firebase and I built a StreamBuilder to retrieve data from my collection but the problem is that I have a list of Ids and I want the where method be for every item in.

I now just can make this on the first item in the list.

What should I do ?

My Code:-

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _firestore
                        .collection('blogs')
                        //Here is the problem
                        .where('writerID', isEqualTo: followingUserPostsID[0].)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshots) {
                      try {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Center(
                            child: SpinKitChasingDots(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        var snapshotDocuments = snapshots.data.documents;

                        if (snapshots == null) {
                          return Center(
                            child: SpinKitChasingDots(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            ),
                          );
                        }

                        return Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshotDocuments.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Blog(
                                userID:
                                    snapshotDocuments[index].data['writerID'],
                                networkImage: Image.network(
                                  snapshotDocuments[index].data['postPhoto'],
                                ),
                                postDesc:
                                    snapshotDocuments[index].data['postDesc'],
                                postTitle:
                                    snapshotDocuments[index].data['postTitle'],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      } catch (e) {
                        return Center(
                          child: SpinKitChasingDots(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: you can use `whereIn` instead of `where`.

Comment: I can't find it

Comment: Why? I can see its declaration. Are you using latest version ?

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: I did not understand the question at all. Also, the posted code looks fine to me.

Comment: I want to return all posts for all the ids in followingUserPostsID not just the first or index[0].

Comment: once I've upgraded my plugin it works thanks !